# I accidentally deleted my video proxy file and now the preview wont show for that clip

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

so I was editing my video and everything was going smoothly until I noticed a file that said BL-proxy or something like that. I had no clue what it was for so I deleted it and continued editing my video. I closed Blender when I was done for the day. The next day I opened it and the intro to my video was there, but the main clip wasn't. It just showed a blank screen and all I had done was delete that proxy file and make the shortened clips into a meta strip then edited some more and made those another 1 meta strip. I tried unmetaing them but didn't work. I don't know what to do and I couldn't find the original clip I had as I could only bring back a copy. Please help me not lose 7 hours of work.

Comment: If you're on blender 2.93+ and have auto proxies on then select all strips and in the Preview sidebar switch from the current proxy setting to something else and back. Then it should start rendering. If not then select your strips then in the Preview View menu, select Proxy > Setup, choose the resolution, then Proxy > Rebuild and then it should render, then ensure that the preview has the proxy % you rendered the proxy files to.